# Parameters not replaced when script from "source code"

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity 2017.2.2 I am using parameters like %host% and when deploying TeamCity replaces those parameters by what I specified on the parameters section - at least when I paste my Powershell script right into the "Script source" box (setting Script: "Source code").

When I use the setting Script: "File" instead and pick the same .ps1 file from my repository, then TeamCity will run the script as before but leaves parameters like %host% untouched.

How do I use parameters with scripts from my repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is not altered from your vcs with a token replacement from: `%host%` to your value when you use the `File` input.
You should specify parameters for your script, and inside the "Script Arguments" section on TeamCity, you can specify the parameters like this:

> -Host: %host% -SomeCustomValue: %extraArgs%

This will cause the script to be executed with the parameters transformed with proper values.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did not really understand your answer first (lack of TeamCity experience), but it makes sense and works perfectly now.